# Automating a task for an app that isn't mine

Tags: java, android, automation

I haven't found a proper answer for this so far so hopefully I can get one on this thread:
I need to automate a task as follows (on an app that isn't mine):

(1) Kill the android app
(2) Open it again
(3) Click a specific button in it (which is in fixed position) and wait 60 seconds.

I've found answers for 1&2, but I'm thinking 3 may be harder because I don't really have an API or something simple to access the button except tapping it in the screen (the application is not mine obviously), and I'm looking to find the best way to automate this task.

Comment: With Appium is possible to automate third party apps... So there is no big deal by clicking a button...
Anyway... if is just to click a fixed button... why don't you try by clicking with ADB? 'adb shell input tap X Y'

Answer (score 0):

Is it a markup based app?

Unfortunately I don't have personal experience with this scenario, but it may be worth looking into WebDriver, or more specifically a tool called Appium. Appium is geared towards automated testing, but the jist as I understand it would be to use it to leverage WebDriver to target the button your looking for based on a selector.

The upside to this would be that if the author of the button changes attributes such as the location or size of the button, it would be less likely to affect your app. However this would only be relevant if it's markup based I'm pretty sure.